# Drupal 7 SMTP emails not getting delivered from custom modules

Tags: php, drupal-7, smtp

I have a website built in Drupal 7.34.

I have SMTP authentication module installed and enabled, when I try to test email from SMTP, emails are getting delivered. When I test email, SMTP authentication module executes without any errors. So, its confirmed that, there is no issue with the configured SMTP module.

Following is the test email content.

```
If you receive this message it means your site is capable of using SMTP to send e-mail
```

I have few custom drupal modules and am using mail hook to send email with/without attachment. Now site was working without any issue will today. All of a sudden SMTP stopped sending emails from my custom created modules.

1. There are no code changes performed for last 16 months
2. No errors or warning or anything logged
3. SMTP is fully capable of sending emails with/without attachment, smtp command line is also working.
4. No patches/updates applied on hosting server

I am not able to find root case SMTP failure, I have googled with all possible Drupal 7 email related keywords but no luck. I cant paste each and every link I visited. Drupal 7 documents is also not up to the mark to address this type of bug.

Comment: you can check the mail log and what errors you are getting while you are sending the email.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki No errors warnings in logs

Comment: Ok, have you checked with the smtp email account if it is not blocked or deleted.

Comment: SMTP is fully capable of sending emails with/without attachment, smtp command line is also working, smtp drupal module is also sending test emails

Comment: In the drupal core just print what headers you are sending may be its the header issue. Attachments need different headers

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki Its not sending email at all from any of the custom drupal modules

Comment: Use debug_print_backtrace function in drupal_mail() function in includes/mail.inc and see what functions are called and what is wrong with the arguments passed to drupal_mail function.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki If I run code on my laptop, emails gets triggered and when I run it on production server email delivery fails from custom module. On production env, SMTP authentication module is able to send test email, but cant through custom_module. Am using hook_mail

Comment: Then its problem of the smtp. If it works on your local then it should work on production. Check what smtp account you are using in production environment.